# postgresql createuser -interactive not working in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, centos7, rhel

A fresh installation of CentOS 7 needs a fresh installation of PostgreSQL, with a new user and a new role.  I am following [the steps described in this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-centos-7) to accomplish this goal.  However, the terminal is not providing the interactive menu that the tutorial promises when I type `createuser -interactive`.  Instead, I get the following blank prompt:

```
[this_centos_user@localhost ~]$ sudo -i -u postgres
[sudo] password for this_centos_user:
-bash-4.2$ createuser –interactive
-bash-4.2$
```

**What specific commands need to be typed in order to get the interactive `createuser` interface to appear and let me give a username, password, etc.?**

---

**The Specific Situation:**

---

1.) First, I installed the postgresql-server package and the "contrib" package with the following command:
    sudo yum install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib

2.) Next, I created a new PostgreSQL database cluster:
    sudo postgresql-setup initdb

3.) I then set up password authentication editing PostgreSQL's host-based authentication (HBA) configuration by typing `sudo vi /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` and changing the following lines to include md5 instead of ident:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

4.) After saving and exiting `vi`, I started and enabled PostgreSQL with the following:

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```

5.) Next, I logged in to PostgreSQL with the `postgres` account that we created above, and tried to create the user with the code from the top of the OP above, as follows:

```
[this_centos_user@localhost ~]$ sudo -i -u postgres
[sudo] password for this_centos_user:
-bash-4.2$ createuser –interactive
-bash-4.2$
```

**So how do I create this user?**

Answer (score 5):

Not a direct answer to the question but related:

If you're like me and you've typed `createuser --interactive` inside of psql, and you're wondering why you've just gone from `postgres=#` to `postgres-#`, you've misunderstood the instructions. Exit psql with `Ctrl+C` and then `\q` and run `createuser --interactive` from the shell as the postgres user.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to have been a typo in the tutorial.  The correct syntax is:

```
-bash-4.2$ createuser –-interactive
```

Note that `--interactive` in this answer is correct, while `-interactive` in the OP was wrong.